# TransactionScope without DTC

Tags: c#, msdtc

For the TransactionScope to work in an environment with multiple database or multiple service hosts we will have to enable DTC in each participating systems. But this has a down side. This DTC environment speed depend on the slowest system/machine in the environment.

So my question is that, is there any alternative method I can use? Is there any other way I can use TransactionScope in a distributed environment Windows OS without DTC enabled.

Comment: You could use a Transactional MessageQueue to speed up your process.

Comment: @JeroenHeier did u mean  transactional MSMQ?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean. See this [case study](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4348/Programming-MSMQ-in-NET-Part-Transactional-Messa) for example.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thank you.